# My tiny http server has a list index error

Tags: python, arrays, list

im working on a http server and it give a error that index is off of array

Guys, please help!

Here is the code:

```
import socket

#Make a socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(("0.0.0.0", 8080))
sock.listen(1)

#Handling requests
while True:
  #listening for client
  client, address = sock.accept()

  try:
    #reads file from response and makes a response
    client.send(str(f"HTTP/1.1 200 OK \n\n{open(f'.{client.recv(1024).decode().splitlines()[0].split()[1]}', 'rb').read()}").encode('utf-8'))
  #HTTP Response 404
  except FileNotFoundError:
    client.send("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found".encode("utf-8"))
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/SimpleHTTP/Generic/main.py", line 12, in <module>

    client.send(str(f"HTTP/1.1 200 OK \n\n{open(f'.{client.recv(1024).decode().splitlines()[0].split()[1]}', 'rb').read()}").encode('utf-8'))

                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: The erorr is telling you what is wrong. The string returned by `client.recv(1024).decode()` is empty. If you try `"".splitlines()` you'll get the same error. Without anything in the string, "splitlines" returns an empty list which is why your index into the list is failing.

Comment: Remove this [0]

Comment: client.recv(1024).decode().splitlines()[0].split() returns ['GET', '/', 'HTTP/1.1']

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the list index is out of range, which means that you are trying to access an element of a list that does not exist. This is happening when you are trying to split the received message from the client:

```
client.recv(1024).decode().splitlines()[0].split()[1]
```

It is possible that the client is not sending a valid HTTP request and as a result, the message is not being split correctly. You can add some error handling to check if the message is being split correctly before trying to access the second element in the split list.

For example, you can try something like this:

```
message = client.recv(1024).decode()
if not message:
    break

lines = message.splitlines()
if not lines:
    break

request = lines[0].split()
if len(request) < 2:
    break

path = request[1]
try:
    with open('.' + path, 'rb') as file:
        response = file.read()
        client.sendall(f"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n{response}".encode())
except FileNotFoundError:
    client.sendall("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found".encode())

client.close()
```

This code first checks if the received message is not empty. Then it splits the message into lines and checks if the list is not empty. Then it splits the first line into parts and checks if the list has at least two elements. Finally, it tries to open the requested file and send it back to the client as a response. If the file is not found, it sends a 404 error. Note that this code also uses the with statement to ensure that the file is properly closed after reading.

Comment: client.recv(1024).decode.splitlines()[0].split() returns ['GET', '/index.html', 'HTTP/1.1'], im using chrome as a client. Index 1 is '/index.html', but it give error in script